# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) with stripe payment gateway

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The Stripe payment process on my site goes blank and stock on charge.php. I am getting this from the error log on my Cpanel:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req_.......) No such token: tok_.......
  vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38

and this on stripe logs

```
  {
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such token: tok_..............",
    "param": "source",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

My payment form:

```
                    <form action="./charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form">

                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control mb-3 stripeElement
                            stripeElement--empty " placeholder="Full Name" required>

                        <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control mb-3 stripeElement
                            stripeElement--empty" placeholder="Email" required>

                        <input type="phone" name="phone"  class="form-control mb-3 stripeElement
                            stripeElement--empty" placeholder="phone" required>

                        <input type="number" name="price"  class="form-control mb-3 stripeElement
                        stripeElement--empty" placeholder="price" value = <?php echo $price; ?> readonly >

                        <textarea type="text" name="title"  class="form-control mb-12 stripeElement
                        stripeElement--empty" placeholder="Descritption"   readonly ><?php echo $title; ?></textarea>       
                        <br>    
                            <div id="card-element">
                            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                            </div>

                            <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

                        <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
                    </form>
```

here is my charge.js

```
    // Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};
 // style button with BS
 document
   .querySelector('#payment-form button')
   . classList = 'theme-btn btn-style-two';
// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

and my charge.php

```
<?php


   require_once('vendor/autoload.php');



   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test key');



   // Sanitize POST array
   $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


   $title = $_POST['title'];
   $price = $_POST['price'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];




   // create customer in stripe
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "email" => $email,
      "description" => $title,
      "source" => $token,
   ));

   //charge customer
   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" =>  $price*100,
      "currency" => "GBP",
      "description" => $title,
      "customer"=>$customer->id,
   ));



    if($charge){
        //send email
        //mail($email,$subject,$message);
               //Get Form Data
               $name = $_POST['name'];
               $subject = $_POST['subject'];
               $email = $_POST['email'];
               $message = $_POST['message'];

           $toEmail = 'mail@mail.com'.$email;
           $subject = 'dolittle'.$name;
           $body = '<h2> Booking Request</h2>
                     <h4>Name</h4><p> ==='.$name.'</p>
                     <h4>email</h4><p>==='.$email.'</p>
                     <h4>Package Booked For</h4><p>==='.$title.'</p>
                     <h4>Price</h4><p>==='.$price.'</p>
                     <h4>customer</h4><p>==='.$customer->id.'</p>

                     ';

            // Email Headers
               $headers = "MIME-version: 1.0" ."\r\n";
               $headers = "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" ."\r\n";

            // Additional Headers
            $headers .= "From: " .$name. "<".$email.">". "\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);


        //Admin email
        //mail(mail@gmail.com,$subject,$message);

        //header('Location:');
        echo "<script>location='example.com/success.php'</script>";
    }else{
        header('Location: bookings.php?error="An error occured"');
    }
   // Redirect to success
   //header('Location: success.php?tid='.$charge->id.'&product='.$charge->descritpion);

?>
```

I am still new to stripe setup. Any solution?

Comment: This often hints at using API keys that are not a pair, meaning the secret key and publishable key are not from the same but instead different accounts. Can you double check that both your test secret key and test publishable key are from the same Stripe account? If it is, then we can dive a bit deeper.

Comment: The  API keys are from the same account

Comment: on the same Stripe account where you are seeing the 400'ing request on attaching the Token to the Customer, do you also see the request just before that to /v1/tokens ? On https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs in test mode? Could you also paste the token ID to double check its formatted correctly here, the one you're getting in your error

Comment: I added this  "source" => $token,   to    //charge customer.  logs my stripe account shows:code": "missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/missing",
    "message": "Customer cus_.......... does not have a linked source with ID tok_1GuM3AIECGYCYoiKrSSWqVRw.",
    "param": "source",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"

Comment: that is a separate thing, looks like you're passing the unattached Token ID (e.g. tok_123) and also passing the `customer:` param. Just for simplicity sake, lets not do that. Let's try to address why the part of creating the Customer with `source: token` wasn't working. Is it still not working?

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I decide to disable the "//create customer" and allow only //charge  customer. then I sent the details of the customer to the website official email for records cause the website has no database.